# Compare a record with another record within a for loop and update the record accordingly

Tags: after-trigger

Here is my scenario. I have a custom object Milestone, child of Opportunity. When a milestone is marked as Status = 'Completed', then the trigger should populate the Start Time of next Milestone in the next order of the same parent with Now(). I have a field called 'Order'. Here is what i have so far. But want to know if there is a better way to do this.

```
public class MilestoneTriggerHelper {

public static void updateMilestone(List<Milestone__c> milestoneList){
    Map<Id, Opportunity> oppsMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>([SELECT Id FROM Opportunity WHERE Id IN
                                                             (SELECT Opportunity__c FROM Milestone__c WHERE ID IN :milestoneList )
                                                            ]);
    Map<Id, List<Milestone__c>> oppMilestoneMap = new Map<Id, List<Milestone__c>>();
    for(Milestone__c m : [SELECT Id, Name, Opportunity__c, Start_Time__c, Milestone_Order__c, Status__c FROM Milestone__c WHERE Opportunity__c IN : oppsMap.keySet()
                          ORDER BY Milestone_Order__c ASC ]){
                              if(oppMilestoneMap.containsKey(m.Opportunity__c)){
                                  oppMilestoneMap.get(m.Opportunity__c).add(m);
                              }else{
                                  oppMilestoneMap.put(m.Opportunity__c, new List<Milestone__c>{m});
                              }

                          }
    List<Milestone__c> milestonesToUpdate = new List<Milestone__c>();
    for(Id opp : oppMilestoneMap.keySet() ){

        for(Integer i = 0; i < oppMilestoneMap.get(opp).size()-1; i++){
            System.debug('Index '+oppMilestoneMap.get(opp)[i].Name);
            if(oppMilestoneMap.get(opp)[i].Status__c == 'Completed' && oppMilestoneMap.get(opp)[i+1].Status__c == 'New' ){
                System.debug('Index '+oppMilestoneMap.get(opp)[i].Name);

                oppMilestoneMap.get(opp)[i+1].Start_Time__c = System.now();
                milestonesToUpdate.add(oppMilestoneMap.get(opp)[i+1]);   
            }

        }

    }
    update milestonesToUpdate;
  }
}
```

Comment: This is called from an after update trigger.

Comment: This question is probably a better fit over on [codereview.se] (which I do keep an eye on in addition to SFSE here).

Answer (score 2):

What you're doing does make sense, but I see one way in which I *think* you can optimize this algorithm. Bear in mind that off-the-cuff claims about optimization should be proven with benchmarks!

```
for (Id opp : oppMilestoneMap.keySet() ){
    for (Integer i = 0; i < oppMilestoneMap.get(opp).size()-1; i++){
        if (oppMilestoneMap.get(opp)[i].Status__c == 'Completed' && oppMilestoneMap.get(opp)[i+1].Status__c == 'New') {
            oppMilestoneMap.get(opp)[i+1].Start_Time__c = System.now();
            milestonesToUpdate.add(oppMilestoneMap.get(opp)[i+1]);
        }
    }
}
```

You're iterating over all of the Milestones on all of the Opportunities that have Milestones in scope. That's *probably* okay for real-world data volume based on naive assumptions of how many records would correspond to these entities, but only you can truly answer that.

However, you don't have to go through quite that much data. Instead, you can change how you structure the data you query to reduce your iteration. Rather than populating

```
Map<Id, List<Milestone__c>> oppMilestoneMap = new Map<Id, List<Milestone__c>>();
```

populate a

```
Map<String, Milestone__c> milestoneMap;
```

where the key is the concatenation of the Opportunity Id and the Milestone Order.

Then, instead of iterating over `oppMilestoneMap.keySet()`, iterate over the changed `Milestone__c` records. The `Map` gives you O(1) (constant time) access to determine if there is a next Milestone to update:

```
for (Milestone__c m : milestoneList) {
    if (milestoneMap.containsKey(String.valueOf(m.Opportunity__c) + String.valueOf(m.Milestone_Order__c + 1))) {
            Milestone__c nextMilestone = milestoneMap.get(String.valueOf(m.Opportunity__c) + String.valueOf(m.Milestone_Order__c + 1));
            // now, update nextMilestone and add it to your update list.
     }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @David. I like the idea of using Order +1 then my iteration. So I don't really need to calculate the size of the list and I can use SOQL for loop. Going to try it out as well.